# Leaflet map stops move event on touch device when Layer removed

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I have an unusual problem here with Leaflet maps. I have a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9r8r59k1/2/).

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}); //.addTo(map);
var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(map);

var featureGroup = L.featureGroup([circle])
    .addTo(map);
map.on("movestart", function({
    map.removeLayer(featureGroup);
});
map.on("moveend", function(){
    map.addLayer(featureGroup);
});
```

My problem is on touch devices, let's say iPad, running Chrome or Safari.

Open this fiddle on a touch device, touch the red circle on the map, then move the map (the circle disappears, this is intentional). But note that the move event ends (undesired).

Note: I am intentionally removing the Feature Group from the map to gain performance while panning and zooming when displaying plenty of layers on the map (I am displaying 1000s of polygons in my app, this especially helps on low performance devices like tablets). I then re-add the Feature Group when the move ends.

The problem only occurs when the user pans the map from within a layer (in this example the red circle) using Touch. Works fine with a mouse pointer on desktop machines.

Has anybody encounter this problem before? I've checked known issues on GitHub, and have not found anything relating to this.

Comment: you should check leaflet issue tracker https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues , I found one which may be related to yours: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3248

Comment: I did that prior to posting here. The one you found is not related to what I am experiencing. Thanks for having a look.